# Non-fermented vinegar substitute for Dijon mustard

Tags: substitutions, fermentation, allergy, mustard

My allergies prevent me from consuming yeast, alcoholic beverages and vinegar.  I often substitute lemon juice for vinegar, but this does not always work.  I'm trying to find an allergy-free recipe for homemade dijon mustard.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Without the white wine and white wine vinegar I don't see how you'd call it *Dijon* mustard. // Can you tolerate white vinegar (which is essentially diluted acetic acid)?

Comment: Hey, folks!  This question is NOT a request for medical advice!  Please stop it with the close votes.

Comment: he asked for a substitute for wine vinegar in mustard that was neither wine nor alchohol.  That's a pretty clear substitution question, and allowed on this site.  It doesn't matter *why* he wants to swap it out.

Comment: what exactly is the problem you're having with lemon juice in your recipe? What is the recipe you're using by the way?

Answer (score 1):

Another allergy sufferer [claims you can swap in pure vitamin C](https://allergyfeet.blogspot.com/search?q=mustard) & water for the vinegar.  It wouldn't be Dijon mustard, which strongly depends on the flavor of white wine, but it could be a strong, fine-grained mustard.

If the flavor isn't quite right, you can also experiment with citric acid crystals (sour salt), or a mix.  For a bit more wine flavor, consider adding a small amount of white grape juice.  Saba (concentrated unfermented grape must) would be even better, although it's difficult to find in some countries.

Comment: Commercially available vitamin C and citric acid are produced through fermentation.

Comment: Huh --- yes.  So I guess it depends on what @daubett needs to avoid, and whether the purification process of the crystals is good enough for him.  Presumably he has some experience with vitamin C suppliments.

Comment: This is why I'm troubled that you've edited their question to change what they're allergic to.

Comment: Nobody can be allergic to "fermentation", which is a process and not a thing.  Since a discussion about that is off-topic for SA, I removed it from the question.

Comment: And it is not our role to advise Daubett on their allergies, just on possible susbstitutions.  Its up to them to decide if the substitution carries its own problems.

Answer (score 1):

It's not going to be quite the same, but swap the wine for grape juice & swap the vinegar for [non-brewed condiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-brewed_condiment)

Grape juice is going to be sweeter than wine, so you might have to knock back the quantities a bit, but it's actually quite hard to tell non-brewed condiment from regular vinegar.